# Linear ODEs with a constant on the RHS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve an equation of the form $a*\frac{dC}{dt} + bC = c - ce^{-t}$ 
I've found the homogeneous solution but finding it difficult to get the particular solution, could anyone help?

Comment: Did you try putting $C=c$? Were you able to adjust that to get the $c$? Did you try putting $C=e^{-t}$? Were you able to adjust that to get the $-ce^{-t}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use variation of constants $y=c(x)\cdot y_h$ where $y_h$ is your homogenous solution and $c(x)$ is the function you need to find.